# readFileSync won't work with me. I tried to print the input after setting it to string but was weird

Tags: javascript, node.js, readfile

Im new to Node.js and I'm trying to learn alone. I have a simple task to do the following:
-read a file (supplied buy the first command line argument).
-print the number of lines in the file.
-I am using the readFileSync method.

The code is running but the output is weird. I tried printing every statement, and I think the problem is in the reading of the data. Can anyone please tell me where I'm wrong?

```
    function numLines(){
      var fs = require('fs');
      var num = 0;
      var contents = fs.readFileSync(process.argv[0]);
      console.log(contents.toString());

      return num;
    }
```

disregard the return statement, please just focus on the readFileSync. While printing the contents, the text printed is full of weird characters, as if the reading is going wrong

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
  var contents = fs.readFileSync(process.argv[0]);
```

`process.argv[0]` is not the first argument passed to your script, actually. It's the command `node`. The second item is the filename of the your script, which is passed to `node`, assuming you're calling it as `node myscript.js somefile.txt`. You need to get the *third* item: `process.argv[2]`

See https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_argv

Answer (score 2):

Without an `encoding`, [`readFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_options_callback) and `readFileSync` give you back a raw buffer you have to interpret in the correct encoding yourself (rather than just calling `toString` on it). From the docs:

> If no encoding is specified, then the raw buffer is returned.

So either specify the encoding of the file in the `readFileSync` call, or use a buffer methods to read it using a given encoding. The [`Buffer` docs](https://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_buffer) talk about the encodings supported by Node, such as `utf8`.

So for instance, **if** your file is in UTF-8, you'd use:

```
function numLines(){
  var fs = require('fs');
  var num = 0;
  var contents = fs.readFileSync(process.argv[0], {encoding: 'utf8'});
  console.log(contents.toString());

  return num;
}
```

More: [*The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)*](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: @Scimonster: Right, which uses a default encoding. This is clearly not the encoding the file is actually in, hence the problem.

Comment: @Scimonster: That said, the `process.argv[0]` thing is probably the *bigger* problem. +1 :-) But correct encoding is also an issue.

Comment: Guys, the problem was argv[0]. The first argument supplied starts at index 2, and I was using index 0. Thank you all for the help

Comment: @NicolasElKhoury: Yeah, as soon as I saw Sci's answer, I went "doh!" and figured it would be the primary issue. That said, though, do note encoding, it's important. A lot of people read files that are actually in Windows-1252 or ISO 8859-1 as though they were in UTF-8, and end up with things being "mostly" fine but wondering why they're getting odd characters when people do something "special." :-)